# compartilhar no facebook não funcionando no iphone

Tags: facebook, iphone

Eu fiz um botão para compartilhar no Facebook, ao clicar ele abre a janela do Facebook UI, mas não tá funcionando no iPhone.

Não tenho um iPhone para testar e estou com dificuldades de encontrar o erro.

Segue o código que tô utilizando:

```
function shareDialog() {
    var url = window.location.href;
    var title = $("meta[property='og:title'").attr('content');
    var description = $("meta[property='og:description'").attr('content');
    var imageUrl = $("meta[property='og:image'").attr('content');

    FB.ui({
        method: 'share_open_graph',
        action_type: 'og.shares',
        hashtag: '#kimaneiro',
        action_properties: JSON.stringify({
            object : {
               'og:url': url,
               'og:title': title,
               'og:description': description,
               'og:image': imageUrl,
               'og:width': 1200,
               'og:height': 630,
            }
        })
      },
      // callback
      function(response) {
        if (response && !response.error_message) {
          // 
        } else {
          //
        }
      }
    );
}

$(".Btn--facebook-share").click(shareDialog);
```

Alguém tem ideia do que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: Será que não pode ser algo relacionado com a altura e largura que você configurou ?

Comment: Sem a altura e largura, ele tbm não funciona :/ e no android que ta funcionando, fica um quadrado pequeno

Comment: Tenta usar porcentagem e faz um teste.